# Minimizing difference between two quantities with uncertainties

Tags: error-analysis, statistics

I'm a bit confused on how to approach a minimization/uncertainty problem. Say we have some function:

$ a(b) = \int_{0}^{b} \frac{dx}{1 + C \cdot g(x)} $

And we have experimentally determined $ a_{\mathrm{measured}} $ and know what $ b $ should be theoretically, and know their uncertainties ($ \sigma_{a_{m}} $ and $ \sigma_{b} $), and we want to know what value of $ C $ gives agreement between $ a({b_{\mathrm{expected}}}) $ and $ a_{\mathrm{measured}} $ and place an uncertainty on $C$. I can easily find the best value of $ C $ by just minimizing the square difference between the two values of $ a $:

$ [ a(b_{\mathrm{expected}}) - a_{\mathrm{measured}} ]^2 $

But I don't understand how to use $ a_{m}, b, \sigma_{a_{m}}, \sigma_{b} $ to determine $ \sigma_{C} $. My naive thought would be to just see what values of $ C $ emerge from different permutations of $ a_{m} \pm \sigma_{a_{m}} $ and $ b \pm \sigma_{b} $ in the minimization, and set $ \sigma_{C} $ by the spread of those different $ C $ values corresponding to the minima. But that doesn't seem very rigorous. Is there a more proper way to arrive at $ \sigma_{C} $? Thank you!